# Distribution Cert has no private key. Valid signing ident matching profile cannot be found

Tags: iphone, distributed

I've been able to generate and use my development cert & provision for some time. I did have some problems after upgrading xcode, in that the login certs where getting trashed/removed, but I fixed that.

I'm trying to create my distribution cert & provision. I've noticed that the distribution cert doesn't have a private key - you can't expand the cert when clicking on it. Not sure if that's an issue or not. When I drag the distribution profile into Organizer, it comes up with the error message, "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain".

I've tried putting the distribution cert in both login and system. I also DO have the WWDRCA cert installed.

Any ideas - A real pain ...

Comment: I've removed everything and started over.

1) Load the AppleWWDRCA.cer into Login keychain
2) Load the distribution_indentity.cer into Login keychain
3) Drag the myName.mobileprovision into Organizer

Error message: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not have the keys corresponding to the certificates in your keychain. If you posted screenshots of your keychain entries and your code signing configuration, it would be easier to see exactly what is going on.

Also make sure you have the Apple certificate in your keychain.

Comment: I fixed this by starting over. Must have made a mistake somewhere.

However, the problem where my certs in the login keychain are getting trashed is an open bug w/apple right now ...

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have still got your private key on login keychain. That's what happens to me. I encountered this same problem when I copied my project from iMac to Macbook Pro. I found out I didn't have my private key installed on the Macbook. So I exported my private key, copied and installed it to the Macbook, and it fixed it!

I've documented the information here: http://www.creatistblog.com/2009/09/iphone-developer-provisioning.html